# With Indesign, how to reproduce a sequence of menu commands via script?

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I have an Indesign (CC2015) doc like this:

[image: n pairs of ovals and polygons]

Manually, I can obtain `n` paths with this menu command sequence:

1. Select all
2. Object –> Pathfinder –> Add
3. Release compound path

[image: the result]

How can I get the same result with a script using Applescript or Javascript?

Comment: ... only few attempts; i'm not a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a bit of code for you that seems to do what you're looking for...

```
    tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
        tell document 1
            set pgs to every page
            repeat with aPage in pgs
                set pageItems to every page item of aPage
                set previousItem to ""
                if pageItems is not equal to {} then
                    repeat with anItem in pageItems
                        if previousItem = "" then
                            set previousItem to anItem
                            set finalItem to ""
                        else
                            set workingItem to previousItem
                            set previousItem to anItem
                            set finalItem to add path workingItem with anItem
                        end if
                    end repeat
                    if finalItem is not equal to "" then
                        set theResult to release compound path finalItem
                    end if
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
```

Comment: Another question:how can I iterate this flow, for every pages of document 1 page by page?

Comment: add `set pgs to every page` and then a repeat loop. Full example... `tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
 tell document 1
  set pgs to every page
  repeat with aPage in pgs
   set pageItems to every page item of aPage
   
   set previousItem to ""
   repeat with anItem in pageItems
    if previousItem = "" then
     set previousItem to anItem
    else
     set workingItem to previousItem
     set previousItem to anItem
     set finalItem to add path workingItem with anItem
    end if
   end repeat
   set theResult to release compound path finalItem
  end repeat
 end tell
end tell`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I'm missing something because I get this error:
"FinalItem variable is not defined"

Comment: tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2015"
 tell document 1
  set pgs to every page
  repeat with aPage in pgs
   
   set pageItems to every page item of aPage
   set previousItem to ""
   repeat with anItem in pageItems
    if previousItem = "" then
     set previousItem to anItem
    else
     set workingItem to previousItem
     set previousItem to anItem
     set finalItem to add path workingItem with anItem
    end if
   end repeat
   set theResult to release compound path finalItem
  end repeat
 end tell
end tell

Comment: Paolo, I updated the answer to match the changes since it's a little easier to read than the comments section. Hope that helps

Comment: The error is still there, but I understand ... Your script is perfect for a single face document, but it does not work for a facing pages document. Can you help me again?

Comment: @Paolo the issue wasn't with facing pages, it was with a page having no compound paths to release. I've reworked it in the example above with some additional lines of code. It should work much better for you now.

Comment: Thanks again. I can only try tomorrow morning. I am not very convinced, because I had done this test: a page with 5 pairs of tracks repeated 6 times in facing pages mode (the script produces the error) and immediately the same document converted to individual pages (the script works perfectly) . So tomorrow morning I will try. I will let you know. If necessary, can I send you my InDesign doc?